# how to retrieve accesstoken from facebook using GraphAPI?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

How to retrieve accesstoken from facebook using GraphAPI ? I have got accesstoken using outh example but it is not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get Access Token:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=223643860987514%2Fphotos
to get album id:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=
to get photo from perticular album:

https://graph.facebook.com/223643860987514/photos?access_token=

Answer (score 0):

Please check what permissions you have asked for while fetching the access_token from graph api .. It is possible that you have just asked for basic client_credentials and you are trying to fetch some other detailed information using that access_token ..